# Getting static name of BigInt64Array

Tags: javascript

From the documentation of `BigInt64Array` it has two static properties. Below are the lines copied from the documentation.

> Static properties
>
> > BigInt64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
> >
> > > Returns a number value of the element size. 8 in the case of a BigInt64Array.

> > BigInt64Array.name
> >
> > > Returns the string value of the constructor name. In the case of the BigInt64Array type, this is
> > > "BigInt64Array"

However I cannot seem to access `.name` property from an object.

```
var arr = new BigInt64Array();
arr.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
// This gives 8
arr.name
// This gives undefined
```

I am confused as to why I can only call `BYTES_PER_ELEMENT` and not `name` when they are both listed as static properties. Is there anyway to get the string `"BigInt64Array"` from a `BigInt64Array` object?

Comment: I need to specifically get it from the object itself, as stated in the last line of my question. This doesn't address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the constructor and then get the name property using `arr.constructor.name`. I'm pretty sure being able to access `BYTES_PER_ELEMENT` off an instance is an implementation detail and not supported cross-browser.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!